# How to create a module Email Delivery to Customer if the stock of existing and empty stock

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I want to tell my customers On Stock products they purchase by sending an email to them. There are two conditions and options and select the submit button.

1. if the stock does not exist then Select Stock and Order Cancelled There, then send an email to the customer based on the selected email template?
2. If the Stock Avaiable then send an email details of your order by email the selected template?

Here is the html that I made, please help me to complete this module !

[image]